# Compile .FLA files using maven

Tags: apache-flex, flash, maven-2

I am using flexmojos to build my flex projects.
I also have a flash project containing .fla files which needs to compiled into swf

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do that?

One solution I thought was to use a command line script to do it and force maven to call the script. Something like [this](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=485)

Any other ideas?

Comment: Keep in mind, since FLA files are a proprietary format, you'll aways needs the Flash IDE to compile.

Comment: maybe try to save as XFL, parse and compile with flex sdk ? No official XFL specs out yet though :( ...maybe some hints here: http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Maven is similair to Ant; if so, check this out:

http://code.google.com/p/flashanttasks/

http://blog.jodybrewster.net/2009/04/26/flashanttasks-compiling-flash-movies-with-ant/

Comment: Good find. thanks, although my build machines run linux and not windows. Would it be possible to use flashanttasks with linux?

Comment: Well, like I said in my previous comment. FLAs are a proprietary format, so unless you have Flash IDE for Linux :p You won't be able to compile.

Comment: I could take the Wine route, but just wanted to see if there was a binary available for linux.